# Correct use of "most" as an adverb

Tags: grammar, adverbs

The following sentence is part of the transcript of an speech of a non-native person:

“*Which is a technique that advertisement companies **most** use it*.”

I think “***most***” is used in a grammatically wrong way, but I’m not sure. Am I right?

Comment: I agree that it's wrong; being part of a transcript, I wonder if it could be a transcription error. Do you know what it was intended to mean? It's hard to correct something without knowing the intended meaning.

Comment: The speaker wants to say:"This technique is mostly used by advertisement companies." My question is: Where is the correct form of "most" as an adverb in the sentence?

Comment: If that's really want they wanted to say, then you already found the correct form, "mostly". Another possibility, considering this is a transcript of speech, is that this could be two broken sentences put together as the speaker thinks through what they're saying: "Which is a technique that advertisement companies, [see, we're talking about advertisement companies, now what I want to say is], most [of them] use it".

Comment: @shapoor The only real problem with the sentence is the ***it*** at the end. That has to be removed. It would be more common to write *use [the] most* or *[mostly] use* than *most use*, but at least from a idiomatic use perspective, it's fine as it is.

Comment: @shapoor Note that [*most*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/most#h2) is an adverb that has the same sense as in this sentence. Any objection can only be based on style, where it would be uncommon in this case, but not on actual grammar.